# Create a Word (2013) document using C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office

I am creating an web application (using C#) that requires to create a Word 2013 document and email it as an attachment to a specified list of addresses.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 for the same. What is the best approach I can follow?

Comment: Best approach would be to use google and come back when you have a specific problem

Comment: Are you trying to do this through COM automation, looking for a library that can do it with Word installed, or create the file by hand?

Comment: visual Studio tools for office. look it up

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to generate Word documents server-side would be to use Microsoft's OpenXML SDK:

> **[How to: Open and add text to a word processing document (Open XML SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478255%28v=office.15%29.aspx)**

As an aside, the classic option to generated documents before the invention of the OpenXML format was to user COM automation. However, using COM automation in an (unattended) server environment has issues on its own and is rather difficult to get working correctly (e.g. you need to handle dialog message popping up, session 0 isolation etc.)